# «С мыслями о...» — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, дополнение

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении:

> "С мыслями о порочном круге человеческих страданий(,) я самостоятельно
>   добралась до двери в конце коридора".

Будет ли фраза "с мыслями о порочном круге человеческих страданий" являться обособленным дополнением?

Comment: Стилистически лучше "Размышляя о..." (тогда запятая понадобится), поскольку в исходном варианте создается впечатление, что не по пути размышляла (это логично предположить), а принесла мысли туда, куда добралась (результативное действие) "с ними".

Answer (score 3):

***С мыслями о порочном круге человеческих страданий я самостоятельно добралась до двери в конце коридора.***

Обособление не требуется, запятая не нужна.

Возникает вопрос: является ли сочетание "***с мыслями о...***" дополнением?

> [**Обособленные дополнения**](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/271-obosoblennyedopolneniya.html) — это падежные формы имен существительных с предлогами и предложными сочетаниями: *кроме, вместо, помимо, наряду с, за исключением, исключая* и т. п. *Подобные сочетания имеют значение включения, исключения, замещения, т. е. **ограничительное или расширительное значение.***

В Вашем предложении нет таких предлогов, да и само сочетание "***с мыслями о...***" не имеет того значения, которое указано в правиле.

Это сочетание относится к **обстоятельствам**, выраженным существительными в формах косвенных падежей. Смысл его не в том, "с чем" *я добралась до двери*, а "как" (***с мыслями = думая***). Такие обстоятельства обычно несут дополнительную смысловую нагрузку (см. [**Обособленные обстоятельства**](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/265-obosoblennyeobstoyatelstva.html)).

Даже в случае обстоятельства обособление **факультативно** и зависит от многих факторов (см. [**Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114)), в том числе от структуры предложения. Например, если перестроить предложение ("оторвать" подлежащее от сказуемого), запятые будут необходимы, появляется дополнительный акцент:

*Я самостоятельно, с мыслями о порочном круге человеческих страданий, добралась до двери в конце коридора.*